# Equivalent command in bash fails?

Tags: linux, string, bash, variables, unzip

So, this code works:

```
unzip $1 'CSE-5500_Computer_Science_Seminar_-_Menezes_(CSE-5500_FA11_Menezes-001)_2011_Fall_files/presentation.xml'
```

But this code does not:

```
main="CSE-5500_Computer_Science_Seminar_-_Menezes_(CSE-5500_FA11_Menezes-001)_2011_Fall_files/presentation.xml"
unzip $1 \'$main\'
```

Many variations on this fail as well... why?
It is remarkably confusing, and I'd like a solution to it

Comment: how exactly do they fail? what is the error message?

Comment: Something along the lines of the filename not matching. Often times the filename would appear to match, even in the error message, and other times the filename would be altered in some strange way.

Comment: "Something along the lines of" is not the error message. That is no better than 'stuff does not work'

Answer (score 4):

Try **`unzip $1 "$main"`**

The way you're doing it has too many quotes.

In the top version:

The single quotes prevent bash from trying to interpret the argument itself, but are stripped so that `unzip` is passed the string without any quotes.

In the second case:

- If you don't quote the argument, bash will try to interpret the parentheses in `$main` causing errors.
- If you escape the quotes, `bash` will again try and interpret the parentheses.
- If you single quote the argument, bash won't do variable expansion and `unzip` will be passed the literal string "`$main`" as its second argument.
- If you double quote the argument, everything will be *just right*.

Comment: I will try this, but I feel like I already have at some point. There was another weird thing, unzip would fail without an extra space at the end if there was a line after it.